# Why doesn't my A4 document fit A4 paper when printed?

Tags: pdf, printing

I use the template [from this GitHub repo](https://github.com/tim-st/latex-cheatsheet).
As far as I know, it must be in A4 since `\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}`, but seems it isn't. When I try to print it, it doesn't fit the page. Acrobat Reader shows its dimensions are 11.95 x 8.27 inches and it isn't A4 because A4 dimensions are 11.7 x 8.3 inches according to [this site](https://papersizes.io/a/a4). I use overleaf with the default setting, the compiler is pdfLaTeX.

Comment: load \usepackage{graphicx}. That will set the pdf size.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for the response but it didn't help

Comment: Did you mean just adding `\usepackage{graphicx}` or I also need to do something else?

Comment: try it (you didn't provide code so I can only guess).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried it. The code can be seen in GitHub repo I provided

Comment: sorry I normally don't follow links to outside pages.

Comment: The a4paper option you give tells LaTeX to use a4 paper in calculating text dimensions. The graphics package will tell the final pdf to use a4 paper.

Comment: @HerbSchulz ok, I'll try to understand how to make A4 paper using graphicx

Comment: Just add `\usepackage{graphicx}` to your preamble.

Comment: @HerbSchulz it didn't help

Comment: Sorry, that shold have been `\usepackage{geometry}`, not graphics. My mind is going blanck today.

Comment: @HerbSchulz no you were right the first time: graphicx will work (geometry also works, as does hyperref)

Comment: the linked document is already loading `geometry` so teh comments to say add `geometry` or `graphicx` will have no effect on the page size which should already be A4.

Comment: The PDF from the tex sources is checked in to the repository and [clearly shows that it is set on A4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk3y8.png)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I checked it and you are right. But my document head is different only in `\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel} 
\usepackage{gensymb}` which shouldn't affect the pdf size I guess. Anyway now I have some starting point to find out what affects the dimensions of my pdf

Comment: the page size is not affected by the content so there is no reason for you to link to an external github site make a small complete document inline in the question, the body only needs to be `\begin{document}hello\end{document}` with a preamble that produces the wrong page size, otherwise there is really no answer or help  that can be given here.

Answer (score -2):

This is default template that give you landscape A4 paper size with right geometry.

```
\documentclass[10pt,landscape,a4paper]{article}
% use these with xelatex
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{TeX Gyre Termes}
%\newfontfamily{\defaultfont}{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, top=1.0cm, bottom=1.0cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, nohead, nofoot]{geometry}

%\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
%% your text here
\end{document}
```

Comment: this does not answer the question. The OP is using pdftex and you don't need to change tex engine and change fonts to set the page size....

Comment: no, that's just a template.

Comment: you have now commented out the xetex bits so it adds nothing to the document linked from the question which already has a4paper,landscape in documentclass and loads geometry.

Comment: no, it is not, a4paper, and text area that fit when printing.